# Angular Expressive Directive Design

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a open-source project for a [AngularJS Data Table](https://github.com/Swimlane/angular-data-table) directive ( still WIP ).  When you look at components like [Angular Grid](http://angulargrid.com) or [UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info) they all describe their columns and attributes in a object in the parent controller like:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  enableSorting: true,
  enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
  columnDefs: [ 
    { name: 'field1', enableSorting: false, enableCellEdit: false },
    { name: 'field2' },
    { name: 'field3', visible: false }
  ]
};
```

which works fine, however, I don't think this is really the 'angular way'.  It feels more like a jQuery widget.  If you look at projects like Angular Material, they are much more expressive in the HTML template vs object driven.

For my implementation, I originally wanted to make it very expressive and expose each one of the inner directives I use, however, that ended up a mess to just create a basic table.  So I did some research on other frameworks and found that react had a nice architecture where you just define the columns like:

```
React.render(
  <Table
    rowHeight={50}
    rowGetter={rowGetter}
    rowsCount={rows.length}
    width={5000}
    height={5000}
    headerHeight={50}>
    <Column
      label="Col 1"
      width={3000}
      dataKey={0}
    />
    <Column
      label="Col 2"
      width={2000}
      dataKey={1}
    />
  </Table>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

I feel in love with this approach, its simple and is expressive all at the same time.  90% of the time you only want to customize the column template anyways.  So instead of this:

```
    $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    rowTemplate: rowTemplate(),
    data: 'data',
    columnDefs: [
      { name: 'name' },
      { name: 'gender' },
      { name: 'company' },
      { name: 'widgets' },
      { 
        name: 'cumulativeWidgets', 
        field: 'widgets', 
        cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="TOOLTIP">{{grid.appScope.cumulative(grid, row)}}</div>' 
          }
    ]
};
```

with the cell template, you could do something like this:

```
<dt options="options" rows="data" class="material">
  <Column name="name" width="300"></Column>
  <Column name="Gender">
    <strong>{{value}}</strong>
  </Column>
  <Column name="Company"></Column>
</dt>
```

notice how I took the React concept and paired it with a more Angular concept where I would include the ability to have a template inside the column.

Ok now for the problem.  I want the columns on init, but not after that.  I want to replace it with the actual table.  Problem is I can never get that HTML when I need it.

So [on this line](https://github.com/Swimlane/angular-data-table/blob/master/src/data-table.js#L308) I tried to do something like:

```
compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){
    var tags = z.getElementsByTagName('column');
    console.log(tags) // equals = []
    return {
        pre: function($scope, $elm, $attrs, ctrl){
        }
    };
}
```

but the columns are never there til later when I try to transclude them ( not really what I wanna do ).  I need a way to get ahold of them before the controller is initialized and the template replaces the inner contents.  Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7lE5s0cTETYiYxfjVcIM?p=preview)!

Additionally, since my directive is scoped ( which I def wanna do for perf reasons ) I have no way to get access to the parent scope to compile the inner template with the outer contents.

Also, any suggestions / thoughts on this design paradigm?  Thanks!

Comment: No idea about react, but interesting approach.

Comment: First, really great approach and finally someone trying to make a real use of angular custom directive. However could you give a sample in plunkr ? It could help a lot to give you a solution.

Comment: @You - ya, I was just comparing the react 'design' not actual react implementation/etc

Comment: k as you said, it seems that the replace/template occur before you can get the inner element. I'm searching if i find a solution but i actually got a question. Why don't your define an inner directive called "my-column" or whatever ? It could be really easier for you to manipulate theses column this way.

Comment: btw, what is the expected output in your plunkr?

Comment: I really like smart-table (http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/). You can use the standard table elements for markup, what I prefer over custom `Column` elements. Maybe you can get some ideas in their code.

Comment: @hansmaad ya, i've seen this before and i actually started w/ this approach but like i mentioned above, this works for simple use cases but getting extremely complex tables ( grouping, virtual ) makes things soo messy and complicated just to get a table on the screen.

Comment: @YOU i am trying to get access to the columns before the controller is init'd so i can translate those attributes to a object for consumption by the table.

Comment: @Okazari ya, I tried that too.  Wasn't able to get it working :(

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the `template` as a [function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile), which returns the actual template string. The first parameter is the original html:

```
var tags;
return {
    template: function(element) { 
        tags = element[0].getElementsByTagName('column');
        return "<div>table</div>"     
    },
    compile: ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I only found a weird way to achieve what you want.

Before someone give a better solution, here is mine working in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZtvGe9mgYHNkEtnnia99?p=preview).

Adding the `$transclude` service to the controller and `transclude:'element'` to the directive

```
 app.directive("simple", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        replace:true,
        transclude:'element',
        template:"<div>table</div>",
        compile: function(element, attributes, transclude){
            var tags = element[0].getElementsByTagName('column');
            console.log("compile", tags);
            console.log("transclude", transclude);
            return {
                pre: function(scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn){
                    var tags = element[0].getElementsByTagName('column');
                    console.log("pre", tags);
                },
                post: function(scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn){
                    var tags = element[0].getElementsByTagName('column');
                    console.log("post", tags);
                }
            }
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element, $transclude){
              $transclude(function(clone,scope){
                /* for demo am converting to html string*/
                console.log("From controller",angular.element(clone).find('column'));
              });
        }
    };
});
```

I tested some other things. But i'm only able to get the column with this and only into the controller.

Comment: I'm wondering how the $transclude will work with a ES6 class ;)

Comment: @amcdnl Does that mean it can't work in your case ? (i don't know much about ES6 classes). If it can't work for you i'll remove this and search an other answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure, leave for now.  need to test.

Comment: check out https://github.com/Swimlane/angular-data-table/blob/master/src/data-table.js#L52

Comment: `$transclude` is deprecated in compile functions as of Angular 1.4

Comment: @Brian Good to know, only $transclude or the "transclude:element" too ?